# Rendering Power BI Dashboard in Angular

Tags: angular, powerbi

Do anyone have a working sample where a Power BI dashboard is rendered to an Angular (>= 2) application?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-powerbi

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the PowerBI report in your Angular App with an embed link.

```
<iframe width="1140" height="541.25" src="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=e91770ca-3d4c-49c9-a389-84f8656779c1&autoAuth=true&ctid=8f102725-4bbc-4a0f-ba03-1a0e913cd18e&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHz0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXVzLWV9c3QyLXJlZGlyZWN0LmFuYWx5c2lzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0LyJ9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

[See more here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-embed-secure-power-bi-reports-in-your-internal-portals-or-websites/)